# Mesa glGetString() version differs from glxinfo

Tags: c, opengl, sdl-2, mesa

In my application I have this piece of code

```
void showOpenGLInfo()
{
    printf("Graphic card vendor: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    printf("Renderer: %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf("GL version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf("GLSL version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
}
```

that shows this output on the application log:

```
Graphic card vendor: Intel
Renderer: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)
GL version: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.3.5
GLSL version: 4.60
```

I have build Mesa driver 22.0.1 version from source code and glxinfo reports the correct value:

```
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.1
```

I don't understand this difference, any tip? Debian 11 Bullseye.

**Add some OpenGL information:**

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.0.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

**Add other information based on comments:**

```
ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9c5f6000)
    libGLEW.so.2.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.1 (0x00007f3b2a68f000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f3b2a61f000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f3b2a598000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3b2a454000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f3b2a311000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f3b2a2fc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3b2a135000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3b29f68000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3b29f4e000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f3b29e96000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f3b29e62000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3b2a760000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f3b29e37000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3b29e2f000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f3b29e2a000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f3b29c24000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f3b29c0d000)
    libmd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x00007f3b29c00000)

ldd my_application 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe0092c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1f23936000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1f2391a000)
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1f237c5000)
    libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1f237a2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1f2379c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1f2364d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1f23b4e000)
    libasound.so.2 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f1f23550000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f1f234fb000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f1f233be000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1f233a9000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f1f2339c000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f1f23397000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f1f23383000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f1f23376000)
    libXss.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007f1f23371000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f1f2336a000)
    libwayland-egl.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f1f23365000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f1f23354000)
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f1f23347000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f1f23305000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1f232e2000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f1f232aa000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f1f23225000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f1f231a4000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007f1f23138000)
    libpulsecommon-13.99.so => /usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so (0x00007f1f230b6000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f1f23065000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f1f2303b000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f1f22e31000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f1f22e27000)
    libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f1f22e1b000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f1f22d72000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f1f22d49000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f1f22b3b000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f1f22a8a000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f1f22a7e000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f1f22a00000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007f1f227fa000)
    libapparmor.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1 (0x00007f1f227e5000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1f227db000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1f227d3000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f1f227cb000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f1f227aa000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f1f2268c000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f1f2266f000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f1f2262f000)
    libogg.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f1f22622000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f1f225f4000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f1f22549000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f1f2252d000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f1f22513000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f1f224ee000)
```

Comment: So your application doesn't use your self-compiled mesa, but the system one? How did you install the self-compiled one?

Comment: @derhass: If `glxinfo` reports the new version number, it likely IS the system one.

Comment: Is the OpenGL context in your application bound to a X window session (the `x` in `glxinfo`), or it is an in-memory context created without a display?  Are you entering these commands on a local terminal or through e.g. ssh?

Comment: @BenVoigt That does not follow. I can (and actually have) multiple mesa variants in parallel on my system. And that's exactly why I asked about these details.

Comment: @derhass: But only one of them can have an actively loaded hardware driver.  So either the extra versions are running as software renderers, or they are forwarding rendering instructions to the driver, which are then executed by the driver (which may or may not use Mesa at all, but if it does, it uses only one version that was used to build it).  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @BenVoigt Not 100%. There's only one version of the drm kernel modue loaded, that's right. but there can be many mesa frontend `libGL.so` (which has these version numbers) libraries on the system, and be used in parallel.

Comment: On my laptop, I can choose per application whether to use the system's mesa version, the latest stable I build, or the latest development version I built. And all use the hw-acceralted intel GPU driver.

Comment: @derhass: But doesn't that string "Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)" reflect the DRM/DRI kernel module is Mesa's Intel driver (not built from Intel source code or an Intel binary blob)?  And then that kernel module comes from a particular version of Mesa, no matter what `libGL.so` you use to talk to it.  I know that with Mesa, you can use GL features not supported by your hardware, it falls back to a software implementation.  But does that fallback happen inside the kernel module (and use the Mesa version the module built with) or does fallback happen in `libGL.so`?

Comment: @BenVoigt: But in the question, only the two different `GL_VERSION` strings are shown, there is no indication that the other strings are different. But those other stings are still part of the GL lib, not the DRM kernel module. And the `Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)` is actually matched to the PCI ID of the underlying device, which won't change in either way.

Comment: @derhass Mesa was compiled and installed with meson / ninja commands. Is there another way that I could use?

Comment: @BenVoigt Application is started from x11, I tried to use KMSDRM driver without x11 (as I do on Raspberry Pi) but the application shows a lower framerate. If you have a suggestion for this I prefer direct rendering without x11

Comment: Added some OpenGL information on OP

Comment: @derhass could you please explain how to have and how to use different versions of Mesa?

Comment: @Francesco: It's all a matter of different installation prefixes. I compile mesa with `meson ...  -D prefix=/home/mh/opt/mesa/someversion`. Then, you can use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to select the version you want to use at runtime. I actually don't know what the default prefix is, it might be `/usr/local/` so that it won't overwrite your system libs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Francesco To debug your issue, it might help to compare the output of `ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo` with the output of `ldd /path/top/your/app`.

Comment: @derhass thanks, tomorrow I'll try, really appreciate. Is there a way to update Mesa system wide without break anything?

Comment: @derhass: Don't forget [`LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH`](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html#libgl-environment-variables)!  And the fact that `ld.so` just [straight-up ignores `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for elevated processes](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages/ld.so.8.en.html#Secure-execution_mode) :(

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of details with such an approach, but this isn't the right place to discuss them. The question itself just strongly hints that there are different mesa versions on the system, but it is unclear where they are and why different programs seem to use different ones.

Comment: So...why'd you build your program as 32-bit?  Did you build a 32-bit copy of Mesa?

Comment: @genpfault ops, sorry for the binary mistake, I don't have the 64bit binary now. I'll edit the OP for the moment. In the meanwhile, could you explain how to build Mesa as 32 bit package using meson? I have another 32bit application that in this way could use new 32bit Mesa

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701189/158541

Comment: @genpfault only chroot, no `--cross-file` option?

Comment: If you can figure out how to get an `apt build-dep mesa:i386` to not break an `amd64` Debian system due to packaging weirdness I'm all ears.

Comment: @genpfault :D Ok, I'll try with chroot. Anyway, I tried `--cross-file` option in the past and the `[host_machine]` section is totally ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. My app points to `/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu` instead of `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Now I can use **Mesa 22.01** built from source. Many thanks to @genpfault and @derhass for their help